# How to get the uploaded tracks and its details of a specific user in Sound Cloud using a CLIENT_ID?

Tags: soundcloud

How to get the uploaded tracks and its details of a specific user in Sound Cloud using a CLIENT_ID.

I had tried to create an APP in sound cloud , but they said it will take a two week to evaluate on my APP request. I just want use this code to get if I would get a CLIENT_ID from the APP after two week. Is that OK ?

$tracks_json = file_get_contents('http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=Here_My_CLIENT_IDc&limit=50&linked_partitioning=1');

$tracks = json_decode($tracks_json);

Answer (score 1):

the CLIENT_ID is something you get when you register an app. Do not misconception it for the USER_ID, that's a code generated when you register a new account on Soundcloud. Everybody has a USER_ID but not everyone has a CLIENT_ID.

You will have to wait more than 2 weeks after you have submitted for an app to get your CLIENT_ID, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/users/:id/tracks` endpoint, which will give you the list of tracks for a user. Check out the [documentation for the "Users" endpoint](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users), particularly the "Subresources" section beneath.